# What can be said about the quotient space associated with Peano's curve?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ be a continuous surjection, e.g., the Peano's curve. What can be said about the quotient space $[0,1]/_\sim$, where $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$? I only know that the quotient space must be $T_1$, since $\sim$ is closed as a subset of $[0,1]^2$. Is it possible that the quotient space is homeomorphic to the square? Another question: is it possible that any two quotient spaces associated with continuous mappings of the interval onto the square are homeomorphic?

Comment: If $g \colon X \to Y$ is continuous, it induces a continuous injection $\tilde{g} \colon X/{\sim} \to Y$, where $x_1 \sim x_2 \iff g(x_1) = g(x_2)$. Then $\tilde{g}$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $g$ is a quotient map. Every continuous open surjection, and every continuous closed surjection is a quotient map.

Comment: Since here both $X$ and $Y$ are compact, a continuous surjection $g:X\to Y$ is always closed. This means that the answer to both questions is "Yes". Hmm, a surprise for me. Thank you, sir.